# Java adding from multiple classes with an interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

Based on the following UML class diagram I am trying to get the total population of all the House and ApartmentBuilding objects using an interface (Dwelling) and I am stuck on how to proceed. I have included the code I have so far.

[image]

Dwelling:

```
 interface Dwelling {

    int getNumberOfOccupants();


}
```

House:

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class House extends Building implements Dwelling  {


    private final int bedrooms;
    private final int occupants;

    private House(String name, double xPosition,int bedrooms, int occupants){
        super(name,xPosition);
        this.bedrooms = bedrooms;
        this.occupants = occupants;
    }
    public static House create() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        House a;


        System.out.println("Enter name of the House: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter XPosition of the House: ");
        int xPosition = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of bedrooms: ");
        int bedrooms = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of occupants: ");
        int occupants = scan.nextInt();

        a = new House(name, xPosition, bedrooms, occupants);


        return a;

    }
    public void draw(GraphicsContext canvas){


    }



    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "House: " + "bedrooms= " + bedrooms + " occupants= " + occupants + "\n" + super.toString();
    }


    @Override
    public int getNumberOfOccupants() {
        return occupants;
    }
}
```

ApartmentBuilding:

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ApartmentBuilding extends HighRise implements Dwelling{

    private final int occupantsPerFloor;


    private ApartmentBuilding(String name, double xPosition, int numberOfFloors, int occupantsPerFloor){
        super(name, xPosition, numberOfFloors);
        this.occupantsPerFloor = occupantsPerFloor;



    }

    public static ApartmentBuilding create() {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ApartmentBuilding a;

        System.out.println("Enter name of the Apartment Building: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter XPosition of the Apartment Building: ");
        int xPosition = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of floors: ");
        int numberOfFloors = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of occupants per floor: ");
        int occupantsPerFloor = scan.nextInt();

        a = new ApartmentBuilding(name, xPosition, numberOfFloors, occupantsPerFloor);


        return a;
    }


    public void draw(GraphicsContext canvas){

    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){

        return "Apartment Building: " + "occupantsPerFloor= " + occupantsPerFloor + "\n" + super.toString() + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumberOfOccupants() {
        return numberOfFloors * occupantsPerFloor;
    }
}
```

Building:

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

public class Building implements Drawable {


   private final String name;
   private final double xPosition;



    public Building(String name, double xPosition){

            this.name = name;
            this.xPosition = xPosition;
    }




    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }


    public void draw(GraphicsContext canvas) {

    }


    public double getXPosition() {
        return xPosition;
    }






    @Override
    public String toString(){
            return "Type... Building:  " + "name= " + getName() + ", xPosition= " + getXPosition() + "\n";}
    }
```

HighRise:

```
    public class HighRise extends Building{

    int numberOfFloors;


    public HighRise(String name, double xPosition, int numberOfFloors) {
        super(name, xPosition);
        this.numberOfFloors=numberOfFloors;

    }

    public int getNumberOfFloors(){
        return numberOfFloors;
    }    



    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return  "Type... HighRise:  " + "numberOfFloors= " + getNumberOfFloors() + "\n" + super.toString();

    }

}
```

Village:

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Village extends Building{

    private static String name;
    private static int xPosition;
    public static final double Y_FLOOR = 300;
    private int size;
    private final String villageName;
    private final Building[] buildings;


    private Village(String villageName, int size){
        super(name, xPosition);
        this.size = size;
        this.villageName = villageName;
        this.buildings = new Building[size];
    }

    public static Village create() {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Village a;

        System.out.println("Enter name of village: ");
        String villageName = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter number of buildings: ");
        int num = scan.nextInt();

        a = new Village(villageName, num);

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

            System.out.println("Enter type of Building: 1= House, 2= Apartment, 3= Store ");
            int choice = scan.nextInt();

            if (choice == 1){
                a.buildings[i] = House.create();
            }

            if (choice == 2){
                a.buildings[i] = ApartmentBuilding.create();
            }
        }

        return a;

    }


    public int getPopulation(){


        return size;
    }

    public void draw(GraphicsContext canvas){

    }

    public String toString(){

        String str = "\n"+ "Village of " + villageName + "\n\n";

        for (int i=0; i<buildings.length; i++) {
            str = str + buildings[i].toString() + "\n"; // this adds each buildings information to the string
        }
        return str;
    }



}
```

I am new at programming and trying my best to learn but I am getting stuck on this, unfortunately.

Comment: You have not fixed stuff which was answered in your previous questions.  You do not need to dump all your code.  What is your question?  *I am stuck* is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

> ..I am trying to get the total population of all the House and ApartmentBuilding objects using an interface (Dwelling)..

You can not get the population while using that UML. Please try modify a bit as below.

- First, Dwelling must declaire getPopulation();
- Implementing getPopulation() within House and ApartmentBuilding
- You need a variable to keep the population within House and ApartmentBuilding class as well (it will be returned while calling getPopulation()).
  After that, you able to cast House and ApartmentBuilding to Dwelling. Then dwelling.getPopulation(). Hope it is useful.